# Let $P_n$ be a polynomial of degree $n$. Prove the following integral identity

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

Let $P_n(x)$ be a polynomial of degree $n$, $a \neq 0$.  Prove that 
$$\int P_n(x)\cos ax \space dx = (P_n(x) - \frac{P''_n(x)}{a^2} + \frac{P^{(4)}_n(x)}{a^4} - \dots)\cdot\frac{\sin ax}{a} + (\frac{P'_n(x)}{a} - \frac{P'''_n(x)}{a^3} + \frac{P^{(5)}_n(x)}{a^5} - \dots)\cdot\frac{\cos ax}{a} + C.$$

Any tips? It definitely looks like a Taylor series and probably I should play with it.

Comment: If anything, it looks like repeated integration by parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is straightforward to prove the equality by differentiating:-

The RHS is of the form

$$Q(x)\frac{\sin ax}{a}+Q'(x)\frac{\cos ax}{a^2}+C$$

Differentiate

$$Q(x)\cos ax-Q'(x)\frac{\sin ax}{a}+Q'(x)\frac{\sin ax}{a}+Q''(x)\frac{\cos ax}{a^2}=(Q(x)+\frac{Q''(x)}{a^2})\cos ax=P_n(x)\cos ax.$$